# "net session" listing GUIDs for computer names. Won't accept its own GUIDs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, command-line-interface, file-sharing, local-system

When I run "net session" or "net session /list", I get GUIDs for computer names:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net session

Computer               User name            Client Type       Opens Idle time

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\[fe80::6875:d6f8:8...charles                                   20 00:02:17

\\[fe80::d1b0:abf:1a...denise                                    11 00:00:00

The command completed successfully.
```

This would be little more than an annoyance, but it won't accept its own output in commands:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net session \\[fe80::d1b0:abf:1aba:c59a] /delete
The syntax of this command is:

NET SESSION
[\\computername] [/DELETE] [/LIST]
```

I am not using ActiveDirectory.

When I use the actual computer name, visible from the server's own network list, I get:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net session \\denise-desktop /delete
A session does not exist with that computer name.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2312.
```

The question is:how can I delete a file sharing session?

Comment: Note: I've tried reasonable variations of the GUID in the NET SESSION command.

Answer (score 1):

They're not GUIDs, they're IPv6 addresses. Looks like address resolution isn't working on your network. Do you have Network Discovery enabled, or NetBIOS over TCP/IP? Are all the machines on the same IP segment or is there a router in between?

Comment: Thanks, I thought no one was going to answer. Yeah, I guess the double colon was a dead giveaway that it's an IP. Both NBT and network discovery were off, but I've since turned them and their required services on (hopefully I needn't reboot). Still I get IPV6 addresses when I run a "net session". Boo.

Comment: If you want to disable IPv6 altogether on your machine, you can add a DisabledComponents key to the registry as per this howto: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852